# Changed Network Label on VCenter Server VM now Unable to Connect to Reset it Back

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I didn't think it through, in vSphere on my vCenter Server VM I changed the Network from VMNetwork to VMotion.

I did this with the intention of changing it back immediately, I sometimes do this as a trick on other VM's to fix an issue, however stupid me didn't think this through on doing it to the vCenter Server VM.

Anyway when I changed it I immediately lost connection and now I can't connect to set it back.

I can't connect directly to the host the VM is on either as I don't have the host password...after googling I think it might be on a sticker on the host (it's HP ProLiant), but it's physically located in a different part of the country nowhere near me :(

Any idea on how I can connect back to my vCenter Server so that I can change the Network back on the VM to VMNetwork?

Comment: Easiest way is to connect to the host with the old VMware client using the root login (not the same thing as the ILO password tagged on the machine).  Or if ssh happens to be enabled on the host, you can try reconfiguring the VM via the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously killed the vCenter port group connectivity. The only way back is connecting to the host directly, either through vSphere Client or by SSH (needs to be activated first).

Another option would be to recover the vCenter server from backup, but then again, you'd need to login to a host.